# Codeigniter Social Register - Integration

Tags: codeigniter, web-applications, twitter-oauth

I'm using https://github.com/falexandrou/Codeigniter-Social-Register library for twitter login and get allow for my application. Everything okay till allow page of twitter. I'm allowing my application and click to allow button, it says you are redirecting to page but it goes allow page again. What is solve of this error?
My settings of my twitter application;

http://s1308.hizliresim.com/1d/4/r3yk8.jpg

Comment: Can we see how you are calling this library?

Comment: can i get your personal e-mail address mate? I want to talk to you.

Comment: Hi Onur, questions are best asked on a public site like this. If you are a beginner it is tempting to try to find someone for email-based support, but people are unlikely to do that for free. If you need that level of advice, you may find it better to hire a freelancer.